# How to find Bluetooth signal strength of a connected bluetooth device

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth, core-bluetooth

I need to get the Bluetooth signal strength of a connected device and I'm getting it. I can see the surrounded devices and I could display the RSSI value to a `UITableview`.

Here I need to make the RSSI value changing according  to my device position by doing this I hope I will get the updated RSSI values. How can I implement this?

I'm posting my code below

```
import UIKit
import CoreBluetooth
import Foundation



class Bluetooth_ViewController: BaseViewController,CBCentralManagerDelegate,CBPeripheralDelegate, UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource{


// @IBOutlet weak var bluetoothset: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var bluetoothlog: UITableView!



@IBOutlet var blucell: UITableViewCell!



@IBOutlet weak var devname: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var devstrength: UILabel!
//var timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(target: self,        selector: Selector("result"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
private var centralManager: CBCentralManager?
var peri: [NSString] = []
var signalstrength: [NSString] = []

var rssvalue: NSNumber!


override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()


   // var timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target:   self,selector:, userInfo: nil, repeats: true)


     bluetoothlog.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "BlueCellTableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "bluecell")
     bluetoothlog.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    centralManager = CBCentralManager(delegate: self, queue: nil)
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    var change = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1.0, target: self, selector: Selector (result()), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}


//MARK:-  Checking state of bluetooth

func centralManagerDidUpdateState(central: CBCentralManager!)
{
    println("\(__LINE__) \(__FUNCTION__)")
     println("checking state")

    //var refresh = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval( 1.0, target: self, Selector:"result" , repeats: true)
            if central.state != .PoweredOn
    {

        return
    }
    central.scanForPeripheralsWithServices(nil,options:nil)


}


override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

//MARK:- discovering peripherals 


 func centralManager(central: CBCentralManager!, didDiscoverPeripheral peripheral: CBPeripheral!, advertisementData: [NSObject : AnyObject]!, RSSI: NSNumber!)
{

    var localname: NSString = peripheral.name //advertisementData[CBAdvertisementDataLocalNameKey]! as NSString

    println("Discovered: \(peripheral.name)")

    var per : NSString = "\(peripheral.name)"

    peri.append(per)

    signalstrength.append(RSSI.stringValue)

    rssvalue = peripheral.RSSI


    println("RSSI!:\(rssvalue)")
    println("RSI:\(peripheral.RSSI)")

   // var rsstring: NSString = peripheral.RSSI.stringValue

    //var rssvalue: NSNumber = peripheral.RSSI
   // println("DiscRSSI:\(rssvalue)")

    self.bluetoothlog.reloadData()
    if localname != ""
    {
        //centralManager!.stopScan()

        //self.peripheral = peripheral
        peripheral.delegate = self
        centralManager!.connectPeripheral(peripheral, options: nil)
    }


}

//MARK:- tableview required methods

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int{

    return peri.count

}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    var cell :BlueCellTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("bluecell") as BlueCellTableViewCell!
    cell.lblName.text = peri[indexPath.row]
    cell.lblSignal.text = signalstrength[indexPath.row]

    bluetoothlog.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    return cell

}

}
```

Comment: You need to periodically call `readRSSI` on your peripheral

Comment: I have not connected to any devices, currently reading  surrounding devices's signal strength. How to periodically read RSSI value using the above code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For calling **readRSSI()** you should connect the peripheral first

Comment: How this will be an answer?